Three way relationship word endings
In chess there is a concept of a “pinned piece”.

Pinned meaning to hinder or prevent (a piece or pawn) from moving
because of the danger to a more valuable piece standing behind it
along the line of an attack.

Here’s an example:

The Rook is typically called the pinned piece. From a linguistics point of view would it be correct to call the bishop the “pinner” and the rook the “pin-ee”? Is there precedent for what would the King be referred to?
Reference

"-ee" and "-er" word endings


After reading https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24452/528175, I’m curious if it would be correct to say primary pinnee and secondary pinee in the example provided

Productivity is not absolute in English. The way to check whether 'pin[n]ee' is idiomatic (actually used by a sensible number of Anglophones) is to check whether it is in a respectable dictionary. For instance, 'strainee' for 'a thing/person strained' is unacceptable. I'd say that standard English would be 'the pinning piece' and 'the pinned piece'.

The king absolutely should not be called a "pinnee", whether primary or secondary. It's not pinned.

"-ee" is usually used with words from Old French, although there are exceptions ("standee", "biographee"), so I'm not sure that can be considered an invariable rule. It's definitely a lot more common to form "-er" words than "-ee" words, for various reasons, which may include a greater need for agents than victims/patients, as well as suspicion of "-ee" sounding a bit silly, and the existence of the alternative "-ed". Pin is from Old English.
